# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am writing a simple registration code. I want to save username and password in db.

While running the page of registration.php on localhost I got this error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Users\Ammad Hassan\www\db.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Ammad Hassan\www\registration.php(10): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Ammad Hassan\www\db.php on line 4

db.php is shown below

```
<?php
// Enter your Host, username, password, database below.

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","register");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Registration.php

```
<?php
require('db.php');
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])){
        // removes backslashes
 $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
        //escapes special characters in a string
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); 
 $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
        $query = "INSERT into `users` (username, password)
VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($result){
            echo "<div class='form'>
<h3>You are registered successfully.</h3>
<br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
        }
    }else{
?>
```

I want to run this page so that I can enter in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if mysqli library is enabled in your php.ini.

Also consider using PDO instead, it is better and not tied to MySQL.